# How do I know when my USB was last accessed and if any multiple files were copied from it??

Tags: privacy, usb

I had forgotten my USB in the computer lab recently. I found it the next day. It contains my personal files. I wanted to know if it was accessed and if any multiple files were copied from it. Is there any way to know about this?